# iOS How to make a book app? Navigation controller + Text + Index

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I am a beginner learning to program and I want to make an app for books where I can have an index on a navigation controller, and a back and forward button, and a view for text/images that's all. The app will display text/images in different sections that can be switched by using the index. So basically I want a tableview that shows up in a little window when I press an index button on the navigation bar.

Can anyone provide valuable insight for this task? Such as the types of viewControllers I'll need, etc.

I have been reading Learning Objective C 2.0 by Steven Kochan.

Answer (score 0):

Apple states that any app that functions like "a book" would need to go through the "iBooks Store". So in another words, you cant re-create iBooks but only add your book to its store. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not exactly a "book", it's an app with rich images that I would create and put in, there is a book category for apps too.